# what is meant by application porting..!

Tags: java, .net, apache, logging, log4net

What is meant by application porting. when iam reading about log4net  i came across this line "**Log4Net is an open source a .NET based set of assemblies, ported from the Apache Log4j java classes, to provide a configurable logging framework.**". what is meant by ported from apache log4J.

can any one explain how a software can be ported in a simple language.

Answer (score 0):

It means someone took the Java code and converted to .NET so that it will run on .NET platform. Both programs do the same thing but one is written with Java other is written with .NET

An example for porting is Video games. Same games are ported to different platforms like PS4, Xbox One so that it will run on these different platforms. Xbox one will not recognize a code that is written for PS4 etc.

Example Java code.

```
public class SayHello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Ported to C#

```
public class SayHello
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porting is when you modify or rewrite a piece of software designed for one platform so that it will run on a different one.

In this case the log4j Java code was rewritten in C# (presumably) to run on the .NET platform.